# Translating this Pseudo-code into PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to code a function that basically gets a "property" from a sentence. These are the parameters.

```
$q = "this apple is of red color"; OR $q = "this orange is of orange color";
$start = array('this apple', 'this orange');
$end = array('color', 'color');
```

and this is the function I am trying to make:

```
function prop($q, $start, $end)
{
   /*
    if $q (the sentence) starts with any of the $start
    and/or ends with any of the end
    separate to get "is of red"
   */

}
```

not only am I having problems with the code itself, I am also not sure how to search that if any of the array values start with (not just contains) the $q provided.

Any input would be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: This smells of homework.  It should be tagged as such if that is the case...

Comment: @Endophahge nope it isnt. I truly wanted to know how to translate that.
@Wh1T3h4Ck5 thanks! will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
function prop($q, $start, $end) {
  foreach ($start as $id=>$keyword) {
    $res = false;
    if ((strpos($q, $keyword) === 0) && (strrpos($q, $end[$id]) === strlen($q) - strlen($end[$id]))) {
      $res = trim(str_replace($end[$id], '', str_replace($keyword, '', $q)));
      break;
      }
    }
  return $res;
  }
```

So in your case this code

```
$q = "this orange is of orange color";
echo prop($q, $start, $end);
```

prints

> is of orange

and this code

```
$q = "this apple is of red color"; 
echo prop($q, $start, $end);
```

prints

> is of red

This code

```
$start = array('this apple', 'this orange', 'my dog');
$end = array('color', 'color', 'dog');

$q = "my dog is the best dog"; 
echo prop($q, $start, $end);
```

will return

> is the best

Answer (score 0):

Use `strpos` and `strrpos`. If they return 0 the string is at the very beginning/end.

Not that you have to use `=== 0` (or `!== 0` for the inverse) to test since they return `false` if the string was not found and `0 == false` but `0 !== false`.

Comment: Hi, so how about starting the code? I am trying `foreach($start as $testvalue) { if(strpos($q, $testvalue) ===0) { ... } }`. I guess that takes care of the starting term but how do i incorporate the test of the last term withing this foreach loop?